# NTFS file corruption when using drive with Windows and Linux Mint

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, ntfs

I have two identical Seagate Barracuda drives in an IcyBox/Raidsonic dual HDD enclosure, one is formatted as NTFS the other is a TrueCrypt volume (both were created on Windows 7).

I have always had problems copying large (>1GB) files to the NTFS drive, either  on Windows or Linux but have never had an issue reading, leading me to think it was a buffer issue on the enclosure (it has it's own RAID controller so I'm assuming has its own memory).

However I previously had two identical Western Digital drives in the same enclosure, both TrueCrypt volumes and they worked fine for reading and writing any sized file.

Now that the NTFS volume has became corrupted to the point that files can no longer be opened properly I was thinking of just formatting the entire drive as a TrueCrypt volume, but this seems like a bodge just to have my external drives work platform independently.

So my question boils down to: What is most likely to be the cause of the issues with the NTFS drive and what is the best way to store large files (>2GB) on an external HDD that can be read from and written to on Windows and Linux.

Comment: I suspect the RAID controller.  NTFS read/write support has been stable for 10+ years in Linux.  Its not an official Microsoft driver, and it could be the cause of the corruption, but the driver is stable.

Comment: That's what I first assumed, in which case do you think that data stored on a TrueCrypt partition should be fine, since (AFAIK) at the drive level it does not use NTFS.

Comment: RAID and RAID controllers are strange.  It entirely depends on the filesystem the container will be on.

Comment: To be fair I find filesystems in general confusing. I have one TreuCrypt drive which reads as an NTFS partition on an HPFS/NTFS container and another which reads as an NTFS partition on an unknown container, in both cases I set the drive up as one encrypted volume. And both of the TrueCrypt drives work fine in the RAID enclosure - could this be because TrueCrypt has to do the on-the-fly encryption so data is written to the drives is smaller "bursts", so the RAID memory has a chance to empty while TrueCrypt's buffer is filled?

Comment: Actually scratch that, it is the RAID controller, it just failed copying a 5GB file to a TrueCrypt drive. I'm probably just going to replace this enclosure with some "dumb" ones.

Comment: I have no idea.  Be sure to post an answer to your question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue was the RAID controller, I was able to write and read large (>5GB) files fine when using a £5 USB-SATA converter.